# Installing Ubuntu in a dual-boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

EDIT: Plenty of info out there I'll get to it before I bother anyone for more answers.

Answer (score -1):

A dual boot would be fine.

A Virtual Machine with Virtualbox might be better for you though. Less headaches and more flexibility, easier to set up.

To learn the basics about Linux I recommended the [EdX Intro to Linux course](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-linux-linuxfoundationx-lfs101x-2). I've taken it myself and it's great. It's free, it's good, and you can do it at your own pace.